# How to check if the component is in Workflow in TOM.NET?

Tags: event-system, workflow, 2013-sp1

We have a workflow which locks the component on save and goes through the various approval steps.

However, in child publications if any operation is being performed, I want to check on the basis of events performed on that, only if the component is not in the workflow.

I tried using

```
component.GetProcessDefinition() != null
```

bu this condition holds true if any workflow is enabled for the component whereas I want to see if the component is in the workflow but with TOM.NET.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
component.LockType.HasFlag(LockType.InWorkflow)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is working.

I also tried doing subject.CurrentActivity!=null and it is solving the purpose too, is there any difference?

Comment: No, that is functionally equivalent.